# MYSQL need suggestion to migrate date stored in db in EST Timezone to UTC Timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

Let me explain the current scenario of my system  which is in production,  before asking question:

My Current Server is in : EST,
Database is in : EST.

Now, there is a feature where we want to introduce a Timezone support for clients, hence as a business decision we have come up to migrate all the data stored in Mysql which are in EST to UTC.

Why UTC, because this is the benchmark or base timezone which we want to keep in system and convert user data based on their timezone from UTC to specific timezone. For doing conversion we would be using PHP Datetime Class where we can pass timezone to convert.

Hence, the question is how would I go with converting my MYSQL EST date to UTC?

Note: all the dates stored in MYSQl currently are in **datetime** format.

Comment: Are you sure your database is in EST?  It's more likely that it is in "Eastern Time", which includes *both* EST and EDT.  You may need to consider [daylight saving time issues](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) during the conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single SQL query might be sufficient, given that table is named `foo` and column is `bar` then this query should do the trick:

```
UPDATE `foo` SET `bar` = CONVERT_TZ( `bar`, 'EST', 'UTC' );
```

Based on [MySQL documentation for `CONVERT_TZ` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz):

> CONVERT_TZ() converts a datetime value dt from the time zone given by from_tz to the time zone given by to_tz and returns the resulting value.

Comment: OP may want `EDT`, instead of `EST`, if daylight savings was observed when the datetimes were recorded. Hint: `EST` is rare.

Answer (score 0):

use the CONVERT_TZ() function to update the existing values in the DB